# Nonlinear PDESolve fails to converge

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm solving a coupled Nonlinear PDE systems with two functions f, g, dependent on two variables x, y.

I use the "PDESolve" with initialized PDE coefficient, boundary, method, variable, solution and method in their required forms.

It returns the following fail and does not run:

```
"FindRoot::stfail: The method AffineCovariantNewton failed to compute the next step.
FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function value is still greater than the tolerance prescribed by the AccuracyGoal option."
```

Then I specify the `"FindRootOptions" -> {method -> {"Newton"}}`. Then it does run but returns:

```
"FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
```

It gives a plot but the result is incorrect noise, instead of smooth solution. "

I've also tried set `"MeshOptions"` in `"InitializePDEMethodData"` or `"PrecisionGoal"` in `"FindRootOptions"`, but it seems that does not help.

I wonder: 1. the reason of such failure (e.g., my PDEs are too complicated to solve?) 2. any possible solution (e.g., re-write some parts in lower level?)

The specific code is as follows

```
(*define parameters and coefficients of the PDE as follows*)

B := 0;(*parameter*)
rmax := 10;(*maximum radius*)
rmin := 0.01;(*minimum radius*)
\[Theta]max := \[Pi] - 0.01;(*maximum polar angle*)
\[Theta]min := 0.01;(*minimum polar angle*)
domain = Rectangle[{rmin, \[Theta]min}, {rmax, \[Theta]max}];(*region \
of variables r,\[Theta] (later substituted by mesh, if manually)*)

cF := Sin[\[Theta]] (1 + (1/(r Sin[\[Theta]]) - (B r Sin[\[Theta]])/
        2)^2 (Sin[f[r, \[Theta]]])^2 (Sin[g[r, \[Theta]]])^2);
cG := (Sin[f[r, \[Theta]]])^2 cF;
cD := Sin[\[Theta]] (D[f[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]] D[g[r, \[Theta]], 
       r] - D[f[r, \[Theta]], r] D[g[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]]) (Sin[
     f[r, \[Theta]]])^2;

c11 := cF {{r^2, 0}, {0, 1}};
c22 := cG {{r^2, 0}, {0, 1}};
c12 := cD {{0, -1}, {1, 0}};
c21 := cD {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}};
(*Second order coefficients in the form of "diffusion coefficients"*)

cf := r^2 Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[f[r, \[Theta]]] Cos[
    f[r, \[Theta]]] ((D[g[r, \[Theta]], 
       r])^2 + (1/r^2) (D[g[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]])^2 + (1/
        r^2) (D[f[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]] D[g[r, \[Theta]], r] - 
        D[f[r, \[Theta]], r] D[
          g[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]])^2 + (1/(r Sin[\[Theta]]) - (B r \
Sin[\[Theta]])/2)^2 (Sin[
        g[r, \[Theta]]])^2 (1 + (D[f[r, \[Theta]], 
          r])^2 + (1/r^2) (D[f[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]])^2 + 
        2 (Sin[f[
            r, \[Theta]]])^2 ((D[g[r, \[Theta]], 
             r])^2 + (1/r^2) (D[g[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]])^2)));
cg := r^2 Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[g[r, \[Theta]]] Cos[
    g[r, \[Theta]]] (1/(r Sin[\[Theta]]) - (B r Sin[\[Theta]])/
      2)^2 (Sin[
     f[r, \[Theta]]])^2 (1 + (D[f[r, \[Theta]], 
       r])^2 + (1/r^2) (D[f[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]])^2 + (Sin[
        f[r, \[Theta]]])^2 ((D[g[r, \[Theta]], 
          r])^2 + (1/r^2) (D[g[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]])^2));
(*zeroth order coefficients as the "load coefficients"*)

(*start finite element programming from now on*)

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];(*introduce FEM package for solving PDE *)
variable = 
 NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
    "Space"} -> {{f, 
     g}, {r, \[Theta]}}];(*define the function (to be sloved) f,g \
dependent on variables r,\[Theta]*)

meshboundary = 
 ToBoundaryMesh[
  FullRegion[2], {{rmin, rmax}, {\[Theta]min, \[Theta]max}}, 
  "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> Infinity];
mesh = ToElementMesh[meshboundary, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00005, 
   "MeshElementBlocks" -> 10];
(*create the mesh manually*)

space = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {ToNumericalRegion[mesh]}];
(*define the space on which we solve the PDE*)

method = InitializePDEMethodData[variable, space(*,
   Method\[Rule]{"FiniteElement",
   "MeshOptions"\[Rule]{"MeshOrder"\[Rule]2},
   "MeshOptions"\[Rule]{MaxCellMeasure\[Rule]0.001},
   "IntegrationOrder"\[Rule] 5}*)];
(*choose the PDE method (currently only FEM available) (meshoptions \
can be specified here if not created manually)*)

coefficient = 
  InitializePDECoefficients[variable, space, 
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{c11, c12}, {c21, c22}}, 
   "LoadCoefficients" -> {{cf}, {cg}}];
(*initialize the PDE coefficients in their required form*)

boundary = 
  InitializeBoundaryConditions[variable, 
   space, {{DirichletCondition[f[r, \[Theta]] == \[Pi], r == rmin], 
     DirichletCondition[f[r, \[Theta]] == 0, 
      r == rmax]}, {DirichletCondition[
      g[r, \[Theta]] == 0, \[Theta] == \[Theta]min], 
     DirichletCondition[
      g[r, \[Theta]] == \[Pi], \[Theta] == \[Theta]max]}}];
(*impose the boundary conditions*)

(*NDSolve`SetSolutionDataComponent[space,"Dependent",{1,1}]*)
(*unsure how to apply this initial guess*)

Block[{e = 0, s = 0, j = 0},
 myPDE = PDESolve[coefficient, boundary, variable, space, method, 
   "FindRootOptions" -> \
{(*Method\[Rule]{"Newton"},*)(*Method\[Rule]{"AffineCovariantNewton",
     "BroydenUpdates"\[Rule]False}]*)(*PrecisionGoal\[Rule] 5,*)
     Jacobian -> {Automatic, EvaluationMonitor :> j++} , 
     EvaluationMonitor :> e++, StepMonitor :> s++}];
 Print["Function Evaluations = ", e, "\nSteps = ", s, 
  "\nJacobian Evaluations = ", j];]
(*solve the PDE. set FindRootOptions. inspect the procedure*)

{fSolution, gSolution} = ProcessPDESolutions[method, myPDE]
(*post-process the PDE, generating the interpolating function*)

print = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {rmax, \[Pi]}]
(*set the print region*)

Plot3D[{fSolution[r, \[Theta]], 
  gSolution[r, \[Theta]]}, {r, \[Theta]} \[Element] 
  print]
(*print out the result*)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit long for a comment. Without seeing the equations it's hard to say what the issues is/are. Here are some thoughts but you should post all of your code.

1. The initial guess is bad, too far off. - Try to solve a less nonlinear problem and use that as a starting vector. Alternative is to try to solve a linear system by removing the nonlinear components and use that as a starting vector
2. Make sure that your equations are correct. Simplify your equations by removing everything that is not necessary.
3. The equations may not be solvable with current means.
4. Re-writing with low level FEM only makes sense for a very specific scenario and you'd get an error message in that case. Since you did not report any such message I'd say, no, it does not help writing in low level code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed instruction. Sorry that I was afraid the code is too lengthy thus I didn't post it. Now I've added the concrete code. I'm looking forward to your further guide! Thank you in advance!